# Disable default lockscreen notifications on Micromax Canvas A74

Tags: notifications, lock-screens

I'm using Micromax Canvas A74 running Android Jellybean. Recently I searched for a locksceen notification widget and found "NiLS Lockscreen Notifications".

But now the problem is, how can I disable the default "New Message" and "Missed call" notification on my lockscreen, which jumps and vibrates for sometime each time I unlock my phone? I have already unchecked the "Show notification" checkbox from the app info section, but it's still there.

[image: Lockscreen notification]

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable the notification on the lockscreen widget, or the system notification bar? Also, could you mention your phone model? I didn't experience vibration when unlocking the phone with missed call...

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
My modal phone is Micromax Canvas A74 http://goo.gl/sxD371
I was not talking about the notification in the notification bar.i was talking about this.http://goo.gl/U63mFt Please see the screenshot. and the vibration i said, was about the icons vibration(or may be a jump).I'm sorry if i gave u some bad idea. :(

Comment: No problem, no need to apologize :) We're trying to help, but previously, there is not enough info (e.g. missed call notification on lock screen, which is apparently a featured on Micromax device).

Answer (score 1):

But I have found **Solution** for this. I have a check box in Display - Lock Screen notification (a check box). It fixed my problem.